# Creating Stop button on C# with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm building a newbish Mp3 Player on C# with NAudio, but I'm facing a problem making a button that actually stops the song, and the play button which when clicked again should start the song from the beginning. Also, I'm not sure how to create the Next and Previous song buttons, as well as a volume rocker. Any ideas?

Here is my current code:

```
using NAudio;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace mp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader wave = null;

        private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;

        private void openFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Отваряме файл
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3";
            if (open.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

            wave = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(open.FileName);
            output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
            output.Init(new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(wave));
            output.Stop();

            //Бутоните се активират
            button_play.Enabled = true;
            button_pause.Enabled = true;
            button_stop.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button_pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (output != null)
            {
                if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Pause();          
                button_pause.Enabled = false;
                button_play.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void button_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Paused) output.Play();
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Stopped) output.Play();
            button_play.Enabled = false;
            button_pause.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Stop();
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Stopped) output.PlaybackPosition();
            button_play.Enabled = true;
            button_pause.Enabled = false;

        }

    }
}
```